# Decreasing image pixel size in actionscript?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, image-processing

I want to decrease an 480 X 480 bitmap image size to 30 X 30 pixel size but keeping the whole height and width intact. (I do not want to scale or use height/width property! )

So if i divide 480/16 = 30. So i need to take average pixel values of 30 pixel elements and put it into new image.

How to take the average in actionscript 3.0? I looked at getpixels() method, is their any simple way/methods to achieve this?

Let me put in more simple way - I am trying to reduce pixels in an bitmap image from 480 X 480 to 30 X 30, the height and width remain same and i expect some amount of distortion after converting image to 30 X 30.

I did scaling but it reduces width and height, if i again increase width and height it just regains normal pixels. Thanks!

Comment: I think you want to look into doing a MatrixTransform on the image to resize it: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=15_Geometry_5.html http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Matrix.html

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't want to rescale? If you set `smoothing=true` on the Bitmap (or Image.content, when it finishes loading) it should have a very similar effect. Another possible course of action: use a seperate thumbnail image.

Comment: Do you mean your image as 30x30 in a 480x480 bitmap?

Comment: yes jason i want 30 X 30 in 480 X 480 bitmap. I'm doing some pixel manipulations like color change and blur, so i wanted to decrease pixel size 30 X 30, but keeping the height and width intact. 

The primary focus is to make reduced 30 X 30 blurred at height 480 and width 480.

Comment: @JasonSturges yes i want to have 30 X 30 in 480 X 480 bitmap.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply then make a copy of the whole image in code, but use the simple scaling to scale the copy, and only present that to the user.  Also look at this from Stack Overflow

[How to resize dynamically loaded image into flash (as3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792979/how-to-resize-dynamically-loaded-image-into-flash-as3)