# Loading more than one child image AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, addchild

I'm trying to load 2 images in to my flash file but getting an error - new to this AS3 malarkey any help would be appreciated!

Getting error: 5    1151: A conflict exists with definition request in namespace internal.

```
var myImage:String = dynamicContent.Profile[0].propImage.Url;
var myImage2:String = dynamicContent.Profile[0].prop2Image.Url;

var myImageLoader:StudioLoader = new StudioLoader();
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(enabler.getUrl(myImage));
myImageLoader.load(request);
myImageLoader.x =17;
myImageLoader.y = 0;

var myImageLoader2:StudioLoader = new StudioLoader();
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(enabler.getUrl(myImage2));
myImageLoader.load(request);
myImageLoader.x =17;
myImageLoader.y = 0;

if(this.currentFrame == 1) {
     addChildAt(myImageLoader, 2);
}

if(this.currentFrame == 2) {
     addChildAt(myImageLoader2, 2);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's usually a good idea to move duplicate code into its own function instead of doing copy + paste:

```
function loadImage(file:String, x:Number, y:Number):StudioLoader{
    var myImageLoader:StudioLoader = new StudioLoader();
    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(file);
    myImageLoader.load(request);
    myImageLoader.x = x;
    myImageLoader.y = y;
    return myImageLoader;
}
addChild(loadImage(enabler.getUrl(myImage1),17,0));
addChild(loadImage(enabler.getUrl(myImage2),17,0));
```

That's not just giving you better structured code but also fixes your duplicate variable definition issue because what's defined locally inside a function stays inside the function.

This might provide some insight:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/functions.html

Comment: Do you know how you add the size of the image? I'm using the same image for a few different sized banners at it's being stretched over the whole thing...

myImageLoader.height = 200; for example isnt working

Comment: You need to wait until the image has been loaded before you can set the size. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792979/how-to-resize-dynamically-loaded-image-into-flash-as3

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a new variable with the same name as an existing one, in your case I'm speaking about your `URLRequest request`, so to avoid this type of error you can do like this :

```
var myImageLoader2:StudioLoader = new StudioLoader();
// assing a new URLRequest to an existing var
request = new URLRequest(enabler.getUrl(myImage2));
// here you want use the myImageLoader2, not myImageLoader
myImageLoader2.load(request);
myImageLoader2.x =17;
myImageLoader2.y = 0;
```

Or :

```
var myImageLoader2:StudioLoader = new StudioLoader();
// create a new URLRequest var, so the name should be different
var request2:URLRequest = new URLRequest(enabler.getUrl(myImage2));
// here you want use the myImageLoader2, not myImageLoader
myImageLoader2.load(request2);
myImageLoader2.x =17;
myImageLoader2.y = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, I notice in the second block that you declare myImageLoader2 but you then use the original myImageLoader to do the load request. So even if you do declare a new URLRequest, you wont get both images loaded.

Akmozo's solution has this corrected.